# Consequence of using electronics below operating temperature

Tags: temperature

I have a DSL modem with a minimum operating temperature of freezing. I might want to put it in an environment that tends to go below that for extended periods. It doesn't go very far below, like -10℃ (14℉), maybe more like -5℃ (23℉) at its coldest. So I want to know what could happen to this non-dirty-cheap bit of equipment if I do that.

My feeling is that you can't do much permanent damage to electronics with cold temperatures, but it might not work very well. Since it doesn't go far below freezing in this environment, it's also my feeling that the device will create it's own heat, which will eventually bring it up to its operating temperature. Since the only time the modem isn't operating is when I'm on vacation or the power is out, this will almost never be a problem.

Comment: @JakeGould Not really a duplicate, since his problems involve a (desktop?) computer, which is very different, but it does make a good supplemental read.

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to know what could happen to this non-dirty-cheap bit of
>   equipment if I do that.

The big fear is condensation and humidity. So if you are sure it will be on all the time, be sure it can operate in a way that will avoid ice forming or even having moisture leak in.

The other issue is components themselves including the case and circuit board. Depending on what materials are used, the sub-zero temperatures could warp or even break parts if they are prone to freeze shrinkage. Ditto with solder joints that might be weak; if they are frozen they might snap.

Now I don’t believe any of this would happen immediately. But might show signs of stress after months of exposure. It might be worth it to investigate [different outdoor enclosures](http://www.l-com.com/nema-enclosures) to see if they might provide a safer “home” for your DSL modem than simply taking it as-is an exposing it to the elements.

Comment: The environment is enclosed so there's no worry about precipitation, which I guess annuls moisture concerns.

Those industrial enclosures look great, though. But they sure are expensive--more than a new DSL modem. It might be worth just seeing how well the modem's own heat could support itself first. Or if you want another challenge, you could try my [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/876270/how-does-twisted-pair-prevent-improve-dsl) :)

Comment: Precipitation is a different issue.  Condensation is when moisture in the air condenses on cold surfaces.  It can cause corrosion and short circuits, or provide a resistive path that changes the operation of circuits.  Heat from the equipment can build up to non-operational temperatures in a sealed environment, so that isn't a reliable solution.  Also, warm air holds more moisture, so there is more to condense out on cold surfaces.

Comment: There is a reason ICs sold to the military are different than those being sold to a consumer like Netgear

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm confused. We're talking about a device that produces heat, so I don't see condensation being an issue. Power loss would cause temperature loss, but the only time that would be is during vacation, which I can control and power cuts, which are very infrequent and brief. If I was to use one of those enclosures, I'd stop using it in the spring, so I'm not worried about going above operating temperature (40℃).

Comment: If it is in a sealed environment and produces heat faster than heat is removed, the temperature will continue to rise, so the internal temperature can get hot.  If the enclosure is removing heat, at least some part of it will be cooler.  For temperatures below boiling point, there is a "dew point" at which humidity will condense into water.  If the enclosure is not hermetically sealed, warm air inside will have higher humidity than the cold air outside.  That humidity can condense on the colder surfaces.  It's why it can rain inside an airplane hangar or covered arena.